# How to get a subelement with css selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I use Nightwatch.js to test a website. Now I have this html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input id="inputTireManufacturer">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select the `input` node. But there are other nodes with `id="inputTireManufacturer"`. This means I need a selector that can select an element with `class="form-group"`, that contains an element with `class="col-sm-6"` that contains an element with `id="inputTireManufacturer"`. Something like this: `.form-group:.col-sm-6:#inputTireManufacturer`
But this does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: But there are other nodes with id="inputTireManufacturer".  — Then you are not working with HTML. An id **must be unique** in a document. Use a class instead.

Comment: I used opera to view the html code of the website and id="inputTireManufacturer" appears several times in different nodes.

Comment: That still isn't allowed.

Comment: however... it works. I just cannot test it. is there a way to get a subelement?

Answer (score 2):

This has syntax errors in it:

```
.form-group:.col-sm-6:#inputTireManufacturer
```

Fixing them (removing the colons):

```
.form-group.col-sm-6#inputTireManufacturer
```

This [means](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py)

> Selects any element with a class attribute that contains the word form-group, a class attribute that contains the word col-sm-6, and an id attribute that equals inputTireManufacturer.

You need [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators):

```
.form-group .col-sm-6 #inputTireManufacturer
```

> Selects any element with an id attribute that equals inputTireManufacturer that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word col-sm-6 that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word form-group.

---

[However](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute specifies its element's **unique** identifier (ID). [DOM]
>
> The value must be **unique** amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

If you want to mark an element as part of a group of similar elements, then use a class, that is what class is for.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="inputTireManufacturer">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>

.form-group .col-sm-6 #inputTireManufacturer
```

> Selects any element with a class attribute that contains the word inputTireManufacturer that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word col-sm-6 that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word form-group.